# How to override the auto generated mule-artifact.json with mule extension

Tags: mule, mule4, mule-sdk

Is it possible to override the auto-generated mule-artifact.json when creating a custom mule extension?

Comment: Why do you want to override it? What is the issue you have with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work around for overriding the auto-generated `mule-artifact.json`is to add `maven-resources-plugin` to your pom and run it after the `mule-extensions-maven-plugin` creates the file. Here is what I used:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-custom-artifact</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF/mule-artifact</directory>
                        <targetPath>classes/META-INF/mule-artifact</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be overridden, you need to place your custom `mule-artifact.json` under **META-INF/mule-artifact/mule-artifact.json** inside your project's `src/main/resources`.

Comment: I have my mule-artifact.json in `${project.home}/src/main/resources/META-INF/mule-artifact`, but when I run `maven test` a generated version is created in `target\classes\META-INF\mule-artifact`. When I run `maven generate-sources`, my version is copied into `target\classes\META-INF\mule-artifact`.

Comment: Not really sure about test, maybe you need to maintain a copy of it under `src/test/resources` ? Not really sure though.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is it that you need a custom artifact json for test? I have mostly seen overriding it to `export` your certain resources, but I don't think you will need to export anything for test. I could be wrong.

Comment: I have packages I need to export for testing and deployment. In my test, I instantiate the custom classes, but since they are part of a dependency, they are not visible.

Comment: You should have provided the context in your question. @HarshankBansal has answered the question as it is. You should create a new question for the test issue providing more details and accept this one.

Comment: I agree with aled, since your problem seems like it needs more background. What I did not understand is you said these "custom classes" are part of dependency. How are they part of dependency? Are your tests for your custom extension written in a separate project?

Comment: @aled Placing the mule-artifact.json file in `META-INF/mule-artifact` doesn't solve the problem. My custom mule-artifact.json does not get packaged into the jar. I was using the test case as an example of the generated file not being overridden.

Comment: It seems that somewhere between the `generate-sources` and `test` phases the user's file is being replaced by a generated file.

Comment: @user1932673 `mvn test` has nothing to do with how the package will be generated. If you really want to see how it will actually look like, you can use `mvn clean install` instead

Comment: I'm not running `mvn test`. I am running `mvn clean install` and the jar file does not contain my `mule-artifact.json`. The file is being replaced with an auto-generated file. Either way, the command fails at the test phase because the custom file is overwritten. If I skip the test phase, the generated jar does not contain my file, but an auto-generated file.

Comment: What is the `mule-extensions-maven-plugin` verison that you are using? I tried with `1.1.5` and it worked for me

Comment: `mule-extensions-maven-plugin` version `1.1.6`. This is the version included in `mule-modules-parent 1.1.9` and `1.1.3`. I just tried with `mule-extensions-maven-plugin` version `1.1.6` and the custom `mule-artifact.json` is replaced. I ran maven up to just before `mule-extensions-maven-plugin` executes and `target\classes\META-INF\mule-artifact\mule-artifact.json` is my custom file. I then ran maven up to and including `mule-extensions-maven-plugin` and my file has been replaced with the generated one.

Comment: Seems like a bug then, maybe you can try to file a bug. Or if you have the license, you can create a support ticket.